# Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit slow how to fix?

Tags: 14.04, ram, cpu

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.XX 32 bit to 14.04 64 bit, but the Ubuntu became slow, I have the below CPU specs with 4 GB RAM, what is the solution?

```
salim@salim-desktop:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               1600.000
BogoMIPS:              6385.71
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

best,
Salim

Comment: use light weight desktops like xfce or kde

Comment: thank you for your reply, do you mean that I should install kde and then remove gnome:                                                 a) sudo apt-get update
b) sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop

Comment: you need not to remove gnome(removing may cause more problems), just install `kde-plasma-desktop` from software center. reply if your problem is solved

Comment: ok will let you know the result

Comment: it works @edwardtorvalds, and the performance is better now. but some error has occured (upon logon) with a window to report a problem but I cancel the window. now I'm working on KDE and it's very good. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need not to remove gnome(removing may cause more problems and broken package etc), just install `kde-plasma-desktop` from software center.

its a light weight desktop and does not require must resource, unlike Unity which is a resource eater.

at the time of logging you just select kde session.

Comment: one minor problem is that the font size is small, for example in Netbeans the words appears small

Comment: @Salim to increase font size: open netbeans, Tools > option > Fonts & Color, on this page you will find font name, click on it to change font size